# Virtual Box 6.1 and Ubuntu 19.10 Multiple Monitors

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, 19.10

I have a problem configuring my VirtualBox to use multiple monitors. Versions I use:

- VirtualBox: 6.1.0 r135406 (Qt5.6.2)
- Windows 10 (native): 10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
- Ubuntu 19.10 (guest)
- Hyper-V (taken from systeminfo.exe):
  Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                         Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                         Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                         Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

The Problem: I cannot configure VortualBox to work properly on multiple monitors. Below are two most important configurations I tried:

**Configuration 1** (works on 1 Monitor): Configuring 1,2 or 3 monitors has no effect. The configuration works, but always only 1 monitor gets started. Manually clicking on "Enable" in View->Virtual Screen 2 has not effect. There is still only 1 Window and nothing gets started. The screens are visible in the View menu, but never active or started.
[image]

**Configuration 2**: Changing Graphics Controller from VMSVGA to VBoxSVGA does make a change. If I use it, now the absolutely same configuration is starting the 2 or 3 windows right away. But no login screen is present in any of them. Also VBoxSVGA  does not allow for 3D Acceleration.

Any ideas, suggestions and advice is very welcomed! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Creating a NEW VM and installing Ubuntu 19.10 there solved the problem. Using VMSVGA with dual monitor still does not work, but configuring VboxSVGA with 128 MB and 3D Acceleration enabled allows me start the VM with 2 Windows and work comfortably. Resizing, Full screen (Ctrl+F) works all nice. I guess, there was some issue with the Guest image/installation above.